# Add a new/unique object to an array when key pressed

Tags: c#

How do I add a new/unique object to an ArrayList when the Enter key is pressed? Right now, when the user presses Enter the previous object gets replaced with a new one it seems.

```
private void txtEnterCalculations_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        cal = new Calculation(lstboxDisplayOfInput);
        cl = new CalcLine(txtEnterCalculations.Text);

        cal.Add(cl);

    }
 }
```

Comment: you need to store "cal" on your class, or better, you create  a model for it.

Comment: in other words `cal = new Calculation(lstboxDisplayOfInput);` needs to be somewhere else

Comment: Id like to know what teacher is teaching thier kids to use an `ArrayList` Either use an a typed array i.e `int[]` or even better a `List<int>` it will make your life easier

Comment: @TheGeneral, I think he is making a calculator right? He may need to abstract away buttons before being able to use a typed array :( that may be why theacher suggested an arraylist for starters?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü agree, however, still...

Comment: @Nick `cal = new Calculation(lstboxDisplayOfInput);` is wiping your calculations. as previously mentioned, you need to do this somewhere else